# Create a table S1 like another table S2

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create a table named S1 with the same attribute of another table Bonus and also want some data of Bonus to be loaded into S1 
The code I used is

```
    CREATE TABLE S1 LIKE Bonus (SELECT E.* FROM Bonus as E )WITH DATA;
```

but I am getting an error which is given below:-

you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT E.* FROM Bonus as E )WITH DATA' at line 1

I am not getting what is wrong with the query I used.

Answer (score 1):

```
    CREATE TABLE S1 as  SELECT * FROM Bonus
```

And in case if you do not need data then

```
    CREATE TABLE S1 as  SELECT * FROM Bonus where 1=2
```